# How to require precompiled module in another module with Webpack?

Tags: webpack, elm

The goal is to bundle AND make requireable a dynamically generated module.

This is what I have in my Webpack config:

```
   entry: [
     path.resolve('builds/intellij/scripts/elm-program.js'),
     './app'
   ],
```

that `elm-program.js` file is autogenerated by a file-watcher in IntelliJ, which is why I'm adding it to the entries in Webpack.

I can confirm that it's being successfully bundled, but I don't know how to import it inside the `app.es6` file.

I would like this to work: `import Elm from 'Elm'`;

Maybe by adding it to entry, my whole approach is wrong. Please steer me if so. I'm new to Webpack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just needs to be resolved like shown here:

https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias

So in the config:

```
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.es6'],
    alias: {
      Elm: path.resolve('builds/intellij/scripts/elm-program.js')
    }
  },
```